# Why do I get KeyError: 'Coloring book moana'. Is this some kind of easter egg?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to iterate along a list of android apps in Google Play. I have a list with duplicate apps called duplicate_apps, and a list lists holding all the apps and it's name, number of reviews, etc. (called google_data), and I want to create a dictionary with the duplicate apps and the highest number of reviews:

```
reviews_max = {}

for app in google_data:
    name = app[0]
    n_reviews = app[3]
    if name in duplicate_apps:
        if reviews_max[name] < n_reviews:
            reviews_max[name] = n_reviews

print(reviews_max)
```

If I run this script, it raises a key error referring to "Coloring book moana". I googled this and it doesn't have anything related to python anywhere, just a coloring book of some Disney character:

```
KeyErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-216038b69f10> in <module>()
      5     n_reviews = app[3]
      6     if name in duplicate_apps:
----> 7         if reviews_max[name] < n_reviews:
      8             reviews_max[name] = n_reviews
      9 

KeyError: 'Coloring book moana'
```

What is this coloring book error about? I feel like someone is messing with me?

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyError` includes the key that you tried to use, which in this case is the value of `name`, which came from your `google_data`.

Perhaps you did a search for Android apps and the results included this app, which has zero reviews?

https://apkpure.com/coloring-book-moana/com.kidscoloringbook.android

Answer (score 1):

You try to access an element of the dictionary before you actually put a value in there. Since you want to have the default value of 0 for each entry, consider using the `defaultdict` class.

```
from collections import defaultdict

reviews_max = defaultdict(int) # 0 by default
```